# Type d'exception :System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm developping w winforms application and i'm using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). and i'm trying to excecute a method for ech row, so i proceed like this:

```
private void olvSongs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Groupe)olvSongs.SelectedObject).Id + "  ");
    // SC_ANPR_ACCR_Matricule.groupChanged(((Groupe)olvSongs.SelectedObject).Id);
}
```

but it's ok only for the first click, when i click another time(on the same row or on another row) i got this error:

```
Type d'exception :System.NullReferenceException
Message d'exception :La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
Source d'exception :SC_ANPR_ACCR
Exception Target Site: olvSongs_SelectedIndexChanged
   à SC_ANPR_ACCR.Client.SC_ANPR_ACCRSidePanelUserControl.olvSongs_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.ListView.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   à BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmReflectNotify(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   à BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your `olvSongs.SelectedObject` is `Null` and when you try to get the `Id` from `Null` it throws `NullReferenceException`

try this:

```
if(olvSongs.SelectedObject != null)
MessageBox.Show(((Groupe)olvSongs.SelectedObject).Id + "  ");
```